# Include Non-Existent Rows in Aggregate (Partition with Preceding and Following Rows)

Tags: sql, aggregate

I'm trying to get an average of the previous six months counts. However, I noticed if there are only 4 previous months, it will only do an average of those 4 months instead of 6 months. Is there a way to make so I forcefully sum over the 6 months?

```
select
      ST.AccountNumber
    , st.PrevMonth
    , st.[Transaction Effective Date]
    , st.[Transaction Amt]
    , st.CurrentMonthTransCnt
    , mt.EndOfMonth
    , AvgMonthlyTransCntLast6Months = AVG(isnull(cnt, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY MT.AccountNumber order by rowid ROWS BETWEEN 1 following and 6 following)
--into #AvgCntAndStdDev
from EDWAnalytics.ML.TEMP_SymitarTransactionsFinal as ST
    left join MonthlyTransCnt as MT on MT.EndOfMonth = ST.PrevMonth and ST.AccountNumber = MT.AccountNumber
where ST.AccountNumber = '0000709510'
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please tag your database (sql-server / oracle / postgresql / mysql / other ...)

Comment: So do you just need to sum and then always divide by 6 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want the average of the **previous** six months for each month then the order should be inverted:
   `order by rowid desc`
   Another option is to use the current order, but with `ROWS BETWEEN 6 preceding and 1 preceding`
2. If you want the average to always be computed over six months you should replace `avg` with `sum/6`.

   `isnull(sum(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY MT.AccountNumber order by rowid ROWS BETWEEN 6 preceding and 1 preceding),0)/6`

Comment: I feel so stupid not going with the sum route and then just dividing by 6. Thank you so much!